# Movie or TV episode, where a person wearing a kind of 'intermolecular force cancelling' devices dies by falling thru the floor

Tags: story-identification

If one remembers Fringe's "[Safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_%28Fringe%29)" episode, or read through [IntangibleMan](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IntangibleMan)  at TVTropes, it would be relatively easy to bring this good association.

A man, walking through the walls, doing random bad things, or things that just pretend to be bad - wearing a belt-like device, which, when turned on, allows him to break the intermolecular attraction forces (or do the forcefield magic, or cancel the gravity, or do the tunneling - I don't remember the scientific background behind that..)

And, at the end of that story, I remember the scene when he just slowly descends down through floors due to device failure, someone tries to save him, but doesn't succeeds and the intangible person gets the (not shown) trip to the center of the Earth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I remember that Iron Man faced an enemy with this power once. He rematerialized between a wall...killing himself.

There was a Batman Beyond enemy with the same power. He eventually lost control of the ability and started falling as well. I think this might be the one you're thinking of. From Wikipedia:

> Peek: The host of "The Inside Peek", a popular tabloid newscast, Ian
>   Peek uses an experimental device that allows him to phase through
>   solid objects, enabling him to uncover any celebrity's secrets and use
>   them to boost ratings on his show. He nearly reveals both Terry and
>   Bruce's secret lives as Batman, but due to his condition, (the device
>   altered his body's molecular structure, making him permanently
>   intangible) he ends up falling through the Earth's crust and into the
>   planet's molten core. Voiced by Michael McKean.

Comment: This.  That's the exact scene/character   was thinking of, though I was remembering it wrong as being from static shock.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a plot device in the 1998 Scrooge McDuck story "[The Black Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Knight_(comics))" by Don Rosa (and 2006 sequel "[The Black Knight Glorps Again](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/uncle-scrooge-354-the-black-knight-glorps-again/4000-164528/)"). The Black Knight uses a knight's armor coated in [Universal Solvent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Universal_Solvent_(comics)) (a Gyro invention that dissolves anything except diamonds) to break into Scrooge's money bin.